# Easier way to convert date() to formal?

Tags: php, function, time

Is there an easier way to code this? 1.6kb to call a simple conversion seems excessive when my servers calling this one alone up to 300 times a second sometimes, or am I just being a prude?

Also to note, this isn't the only conversion function I've written like this and the servers building decently fast (~0.3%/24hr).

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance! :)

```
<?php
function date2formal($a) {
    $y = substr($a, 0, 4);
    switch(substr($a, 5, 2);) {
        case "01": $m = "January"; break;
        case "02": $m = "February"; break;
        case "03": $m = "March"; break;
        case "04": $m = "April"; break;
        case "05": $m = "May"; break;
        case "06": $m = "June"; break;
        case "07": $m = "July"; break;
        case "08": $m = "August"; break;
        case "09": $m = "September"; break;
        case "10": $m = "October"; break;
        case "11": $m = "November"; break;
        case "12": $m = "December"; break;
    }
    switch(substr($a, 8, 2)) {
        case "01": $d = "1st"; break;
        case "02": $d = "2nd"; break;
        case "03": $d = "3rd"; break;
        case "04": $d = "4th"; break;
        case "05": $d = "5th"; break;
        case "06": $d = "6th"; break;
        case "07": $d = "7th"; break;
        case "08": $d = "8th"; break;
        case "09": $d = "9th"; break;
        case "10": $d = "10th"; break;
        case "11": $d = "11th"; break;
        case "12": $d = "12th"; break;
        case "13": $d = "13th"; break;
        case "14": $d = "14th"; break;
        case "15": $d = "15th"; break;
        case "16": $d = "16th"; break;
        case "17": $d = "17th"; break;
        case "18": $d = "18th"; break;
        case "19": $d = "19th"; break;
        case "20": $d = "20th"; break;
        case "21": $d = "21st"; break;
        case "22": $d = "22nd"; break;
        case "23": $d = "23rd"; break;
        case "24": $d = "24th"; break;
        case "25": $d = "25th"; break;
        case "26": $d = "26th"; break;
        case "27": $d = "27th"; break;
        case "28": $d = "28th"; break;
        case "29": $d = "29th"; break;
        case "30": $d = "30th"; break;
        case "31": $d = "31st"; break;
    }
    return $m.", ".$d.", ".$y;
}
?>
```

Thank you!!!

I slightly tweaked your answer to save a couple bytes and the result in compairson to my original code showed ~0.113%/client over a 15 min live test! (overall, with all functions will save ALOT more... est. >2%!)

```
function date2formal($a) {$b = new DateTime(substr($a, 0, 10)); return $b->format('F, jS, Y');}
```

Comment: Consider working with date using DateTimeInterface, or at least date() function. Then you will have many useful functions, like https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: Added an example (see answer). What about dates and times, PHP has prebuilt functionality which covers 99% of cases, IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example using DateTime:

```
$dateStr = '2021-07-20';
$date = new DateTime($dateStr);
$dateFormated = $date->format('F, jS, Y');
```

Comment: Thank you! You just cut my coding by like 95%!